# How to increase count by 100 to every data

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I am trying to increase the views of every user by 100 but it updates all users view by adding the view in the last data of the table.

```
$views = '100'; 
  
    $res_query = "SELECT * FROM inventory_test WHERE status='0' AND role='0'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $res_query);
    
    foreach($result as $res){
        $visiter = $res['visiter'];
        $update_visiter = "UPDATE inventory_test SET visiter = '$visiter'+'$views'";
        $run_update=mysqli_query($conn, $update_visiter);
    }
    
    $msg="Views has been successfully updated.";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
$sql = "UPDATE inventory_test SET visiter = visiter + 100 WHERE status='0' AND role='0'";
mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
```

No need to perform a select before the update in that case.